# How to compute $\ker(p_1\otimes p_2)$ using only the universal property?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

Suppose $M$ and $N$ are $R$-modules (in which $R$ is a commutative ring with unity) and $A\subset M$ and $B\subset N$ are submodules. Then, there are natural projections $p_1:M\rightarrow M/A$ and $p_2:N\rightarrow N/B$. By the universal property of the tensor product  we know that there is a homomorphism $$p_1\otimes p_2: M\otimes N 
\rightarrow \frac{M}{A}\otimes \frac{N}{B} $$

My question is if we can obtain the kernel of this map in terms of $M, N, A$ and $B$?

I am trying only to use the universal property (I don't like using any concrete definition of the tensor product, since proofs always get really messy and complicated).

What we know is that $$(p_1\otimes p_2)\circ \pi = \pi'\circ(p_1\times p_2) $$ in which $\pi:M\times N\rightarrow M\otimes N$ and $\pi':M/A\times N/B\rightarrow M/A\otimes N/B$ are the bilinear maps from the universal property.

I don't see how to extract the kernel with only this. It would help if the bilinear maps from the universal property, $\pi$ and $\pi'$, were injective, is that a fact? I don't think so, I wasn't able to prove it.

Comment: At the very least you need to prove that given an exact sequence $A\to B\to C\to 0$, tensoring it with $D$ gives an *exact* sequence $A\otimes D\to B\otimes D\to C\otimes D\to 0$.

Comment: @Kapil Thanks. I got it. In the end for any two surjective homorphisms $f:A\rightarrow B$ and $g:C\rightarrow D$ we have that $\ker(f\otimes g)$ is the submodule generated by $\ker(f)\otimes C \cup A\otimes \ker(g)$